# How to make my Google Cloud Load Balancer work?

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, dns, load-balancing, google-cloud-load-balancer

I follow Document for Creating Content-Based Load Balancing: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/content-based-example

I want to reach external address with https. I want load balancer to connect to VM with simple http.

Both VMs work as expected and are returning proper answet when reached by IP address. LB's settings seem fine. Both health checks are passing and Google SSL Certificate is ACTIVE.

However, when I try to reach Load Balancer's IP address or domain I get 502.

LB IP is 35.244.161.226 wciel.pl

Load Balancer's logs show `statusDetails:  "failed_to_connect_to_backend"`

I attached screens of my Google Cloud Console.

Please advice.

```
me@machine:$ gcloud beta compute ssl-certificates list
NAME                   TYPE     CREATION_TIMESTAMP             EXPIRE_TIME                    MANAGED_STATUS
wciel-pl-certificate2  MANAGED  2019-08-11T03:20:15.971-07:00  2019-11-09T01:27:44.000-08:00  ACTIVE
    www.wciel.pl: ACTIVE
```

[image: Load Balancer status]
[image: Backend settings]
[image: Frontend settings]
[image: Firewall settings]

Comment: You have configured your backends to use HTTPS. Did you also configure HTTPS on your backends (did you setup SSL for your web servers)? Normally, unless you need high security, configure your backends with HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a mismatch in back end service configuration. From the details of web-map-backend-service its seems like your service listening on port 80. However, when you have configured backend service you have configured it with port 443.

If you don't require  secure communication between LB to VM, I would recommend followings:

- Change backend protocol from HTTPS to HTTP
- Edit backend Port numbers from 443 to 80

Save and update the configuration.